# JDK 8, Java time parse issue when excessing the days of month

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

First of all I've examined the java doc of [LocalDate.parse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) but it doesn't suit for my question.

When trying to parse date: `31.02.2015` LocalDate.parse returns `28.02.2015` which is wrong.

```
 LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( "31.02.2015", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM.yyyy" ) );
 System.out.println( localDate );
```

This prints:

```
2015-02-28
```

But when I try to give a day which is bigger than `31` it throws an exception. In my opinion it should have thrown exception when I give a day bigger than corresponding month's days. In this situation `28` is the biggest day.

```
 LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( "32.02.2015", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM.yyyy" ) );
 System.out.println( localDate );
```

This throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '32.02.2015' could not be parsed: Invalid value for DayOfMonth (valid values 1 - 28/31): 32
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1918)
```

Is this the normal behaviour or some kind of bug ? Am I missing something ?

> p.s. I'm not asking for the implementation details..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#SMART) for this behavior.

Comment: Well, this isnt an expected behaviour...

Comment: Agreed. IMO, any kind of "you said X but I know better" behaviour like this which you don't need to actively choose to use isn't "smart".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: It's a pity that ResolverStyle.SMART is the default.

Comment: Of course, in my opinion they should change this behaviour..